# docker compose empty volumes (if folder) mount from wsl using docker toolbox

Tags: docker, ubuntu, docker-compose, windows-subsystem-for-linux, docker-toolbox

I am running docker compose command to run the app in docker. But, volumes defined in yml are empty. If I mount a single file, it is working. But, when I mount a directory from windows, I can see the directory, but it is empty.

This is my docker-compose command.

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose.dev.yml -f docker-compose.test.yml -f docker-compose.test.local.yml run --rm app /bin/sh
```

Below is the content of my yml file:

```
version: "3"
services:
  app:
    environment:
      - NODE_ENV=test
      - TEST_DB_HOSTNAME=database
      - DB_HOSTNAME=database
      - DB_MIGRATE_ENV=test-docker
    volumes:
      - .jshintignore:/home/test_app/src/.jshintignore
      - .jshintrc:/home/test_app/src/.jshintrc
      - ./nuke-rebuild-test-db.js:/home/gofar/src/nuke-rebuild-test-db.js
      - ./test_folder:/home/test_app/src/test_folder
      - ./database:/home/test_app/src/database
      - ./server:/home/test_app/src/server
      - ./common:/home/test_app/src/common
      - ./coverage:/home/test_app/src/coverage
```

From above, nuke-rebuild-test-db.js file gets copied into container. I can see test_folder too. But, if I look inside the folder it is empty.

Below are what I have done to make docker work in my Windows 10 Home system where I have docker toolbox.

Below is the config that connects my Ubuntu WSL in my windows machine with Docker Toolbox.
[image]

For my root directory to be compatible with linux, I have added following to /etc/wsl.conf fiel

```
[automount]
root = /
options = "metadata"
```

I have added my application folder in Shared Folders list in Oracle VM Virtual Box too even though the single files are being mounted.

Thanks.

Comment: 1. Have you tried the same using the Windows version of docker-compose.exe? Same result? 2. Where are the directories located? for example /test_folder is in c:\Users\ ..... ?

Comment: Yes. The project folder is in c:/Users directory. I do have docker-compose in my windows machine. But, since I am using Ubuntu WSL, I think it uses its own docker-compose.

```C:\Users\bikash>docker-compose --version
docker-compose version 1.23.2, build 1110ad01```

Comment: Well, check it if you haven't installed docker-compose for Linux in WSL you are probably using the Windows version from WSL. If you are using the Linux one I don't know what is happening.

Comment: docker-compose is installed in my ubuntu wsl. I can see that the docker-compose in docker toolbox for windows and docker-compose for my ubuntu wsl are also different.

docker-compose in docker toolbox
```bikash@DESKTOP-VGO9UIB MINGW64 /c/Program Files/Docker Toolbox
$ docker-compose --version                                                                                                                       docker-compose version 1.23.2, build 1110ad01```


docker-compose in ubuntu wsl
``` /c docker-compose --version
docker-compose version 1.22.0, build f46880fe```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If Your directory from which You run docker-compose is an WSL /home directory this won't work.

You need to have files outside WSL filesystem which will map to docker image mounted windows shares. By default docker toolbox mounts windows C to /c in boot2docker VM. That's why in WSL it is suggested to add / root automount. So You will have Your C: drive in /c . But no one writes about the /home in wsl and volume mounts in windows docker toolbox ( which is using Virtual Box image for docker )

The same issue was already discussed here:
https://superuser.com/questions/1344407/docker-on-wsl-wont-bind-mount-home/1378927

https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/2151

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I will try those methods in future but for the moment the best solution I had was install ubuntu. There's been no issue with running docker on ubuntu and moreover the projects have linux commands in Makefile. I hope windows will give same experience like on linux OS.

Answer (score 3):

I had a very similar error and it turned out to be an issue with docker-compose as installed in WSL. The version of docker-compose installed inside WSL was not handling volume binding correctly. This was fixed by removing `/usr/local/bin/docker-compose` from the WSL install and instead aliasing the windows exe `alias docker-compose="/mnt/c/Program\ Files/Docker/Docker/resources/bin/docker-compose.exe"`

Comment: I suppose you're using wsl2 ? afai tried - I canpt do that  with wsl1 :(

Comment: `The command 'docker-compose' could not be found in this WSL 1 distro.
We recommend to convert this distro to WSL 2 and activate
the WSL integration in Docker Desktop settings.

See https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/wsl/ for details.` - and that's even when running explicitly as `/mnt/c/Program\ Files/Docker/Docker/resources/bin/docker-compose`

Comment: omg! I found it! there's an sh file in `/mnt/c/Program\ Files/Docker/Docker/resources/bin/` called `docker-compose`, side by side with `docker-compose.exe` which spits this error! I suppose it's trying to act as a fallback of a friendly error but there's probably some invalid assumption about path resolutions that cases this quirk

Answer (score 0):

Like @Damo, I faced a similar issue due to docker-compose in WSL not binding volumes correctly, resulting in the volumes not mounting at all.

In WSL2 and with Docker Desktop, you can simply change from using the separate `docker-compose` to using `docker compose` (note, no hyphen), which is a recent plugin added to Docker to handle this.